# Tangent of a Straight Line

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I just got back a math test in my EF Calc class, and I disagree with my teacher on this one problem. We are using derivatives to determine equations of lines tangent to a given equation. The equation given was: $f(x) = 27$

My response was "No Solution. Not a Curve." My teacher responded by saying that $y = 27$ was the correct answer. My argument is that these two lines have an infinite number of intersections, while my teacher says they only intersect once. So, my question is whether two lines with the same equation intersect once or infinitely.

I apologize if this question is of a lower degree of difficulty than the rest of the site, but this seemed the best place to ask. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: you just have to define clearly what  it means for a line to be tangent to a curve(including a line).

Comment: A tangent can intersect more than once: think about a cubic: it is easy enough to find that any tangent to it will intersect it again, simply based on the fact that a cubic goes to infinity faster than a linear function. Similarly here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $f(x) = 27$ means that for every $x \in \Bbb R$, $f$ gives back the value $27$. This is a well defined function. It is not an injective function, though (do you remember the definition?).

The tangent line to the graph of $f$ at $x_0$ is given by: $$y-f(x_0) = f'(x_0)(x-x_0).$$ If $f$ is constant, its derivative is zero at every point. And the value at every point is just a constant. Hence: $$y - 27 = 0\cdot (x-x_0) \implies y = 27.$$ So $y=27$ is the equation of the line you seek. At every point of the graph, the line is the same. Here we don't have a "tangent" line, as you have noticed. You can think of that line as the optimal **linear** approximation to the function near the point. So it is natural to conclude that for linear functions $f(x) = ax+b$ (our particular case is $a=0$ and $b=27$), the "tangent" line will be the function itself.

Comment: I understand most of what you're saying, my problem was only with the line being tangent to the equation. I think of a tangent intersecting the equation at one point, and then I think of two lines on top of each other as intersecting at all x values. That may be a misconception, but I just can't see how the same equation intersects the line only once.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. But if you **define** the tangent line by the equation $$y-f(x_0) = f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$$ and then say that two curves are tangent at a point $x_0$ if their tangent lines (in the above sense) are the same, then we don't have this problem..

Comment: Alright. I'm sort of throwing in the hat and accepting that I should have simply used the equation. I assumed it was a trick question because we had always found tangents of curves, never of lines. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @J.Roberts "I think of a tangent intersecting the equation at one point," and it does... one point *and* a line of points.

Answer (score 3):

The underlying problem that confuses you is to decide what it *means* for a line to be tangent to a curve.

In the particular case of *circles*, it happens that the tangents to a circle are precisely those straight lines that has exactly one point in common with the circle. It is tempting to make this into a *definition*, but it doesn't really work well for curves other than circles (and a group of sufficiently circle-like curves such as ellipses, namely smooth convex closed curves). The problem is that the *global* property of intersecting the circle exactly once doesn't really capture the essentially local *intuition* of what it means to be a tangent, namely that it "has the same direction of the curve" at the point of tangency.

For example the one-intersection-point definition would imply that the axis of a parabola is a tangent to it, which intuitively ought to be absurd -- the axis is *perpendicular* to the parabola, not tangent to it.

It turns out that it is not at all straightforward to define tangents for arbitrary curves -- essentially, figuring out a workable definition was the problem calculus was originally invented to do, and I can't suggest any working definition that doesn't involve calculus either openly or in disguise. (I'll offer to try to shoot down any other proposed definition on intuitive grounds, but that depends on us agreeing about what the intuition of "has the same direction as the curve" means).

In the end it seems that you just have to accept that the calculus based definition (or family of definitions) of "tangent" is what the mathematical community has collectively decided to use the word "tangent" for when we're talking about arbitrary curves. This definition gives the expected result for tangents to circles, and also produces tangents that agree with intuition for curves that it gives tangents for at all. It's also quite useful in practice, and utility plus consistency with the restricted case of circles is enough to make it a good definition.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I should have added "and does not cross" to my definition, as Ethan mentioned. My main issue was that a line is not a curve, so by my thought process there should be no tangent.

Comment: @J.Roberts Mathematically, a line is a curve with zero curvature. Math terminology does not always conform to non-technical dictionary definitions.

Comment: @J.Roberts: Well, "does not cross" is also hard to make precise with satisfactory result. For example, we'd certainly want the curve $y=x^3$ to have the $x$-axis as a tangent, but explaining in which sense the $x$ axis "does not cross", whereas $y=-0.0001x$ _does_ can be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid your teacher is right. If the lines have the same equation, they are the same lines. No need to look for intersections. However, the only tangent line to the equation $f(x) = 27$ is in fact $y=27$, since for every $x$, the slope of the tangent line is 0, which is a straight line $y=27$.

Comment: If the teacher "says that they [the line and itself] only intersect once", then I wouldn't say he is right -- even though he reaches a correct conclusion from this rather baffling claim.

Comment: @HenningMakholm yeah. The teacher has the right answer, but his explanation is not valid.

Comment: Can either of you provide an explanation as to why the same line is correct? I understand how it is correct through plugging it into the equation, but conceptually it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @J.Roberts Consider a circle and the top point is at y=27 no matter what. If you draw the tangent line to that top point, you will get a line with y=27. Same concept, except that is the case for any x.

Comment: @J.Roberts The definition of "tangent" starts with your intuitive idea. The tangent line "touches the curve just once and doesn't cross it". Then you have to make that definition precise - using the idea of the derivative of a function at a point. It can then happen that the precise definition covers more cases than your intuitive idea. If you're a research mathematician you can decide whether to try a different definition. As a student, you're stuck with the one that mathematicians have found the most useful.

Comment: @EthanBolker I don't have much experience with tangents, and the broad definition is all that I've been taught at this point. I assume that I'll be going deeper next year in AP Calc, and then I'll be able to understand. This is the first time I've been asked to find the tangent of a line, which is why it confused me. Thanks for the help everyone.